SwiftUI pattern for handling independent events/triggers in self-contained Views?
I have a View which is self-contained, in that it handles its own state.
The View maintains a list of Particle models. The View manages the life cycle and rendering of each Particle.
I want to trigger the View to create a new Particle, in an ad-hoc fashion, say in response to a timer or user input.
Each Particle is independent. There can be any number of Particles managed by the View, thus any number of calls to the trigger.
Currently, I am using an @Observable view model.
The view model has a flag 'particleRequested'.
To manage this flag, I call a convenience function on the view model:
func requestParticle() {
    guard particleRequested == false else { return }

    particleRequested = true
    
    // Wait a brief moment, then reset the flag.
    Task { @MainActor [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.01))
        self.particleRequested = false
    }
}

In the View itself, I only observe changes to the flag:
.onChange(of: viewModel.particleRequested, { _, newValue in
    if newValue {
        addParticle()  // Modifies View's state.
    }
})

This feels... jank. The whole approach smells. Is there a better, cleaner way?

Your general idea is correct - use onChange to detect a change in a view update and perform the desired action. Your current code can be simplified a lot:

you don't need a view model class
you don't need to trigger the action on true. Trigger the action whenever the value changes
so there is no need to reset the value after a delay

struct Particles<Trigger: Equatable>: View {
    @State private var particles = [String]()
    let newParticleTrigger: Trigger
    
    var body: some View {
        List(particles, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
        .onChange(of: newParticleTrigger) {
            particles.append(UUID().uuidString)
        }
    }
}

// Example usage:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var newParticleTrigger = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Foo") {
            newParticleTrigger.toggle()
        }
        Particles(newParticleTrigger: newParticleTrigger)
    }
}

The same pattern is used in many SwiftUI built-in views and modifiers, such as PhaseAnimator, sensoryFeedback, task(id:) and arguably any presentation modifier like sheet, confirmationDialog etc.
If you have multiple different things you want to trigger, just put all the triggers into a struct,
struct Particles: View {
    struct Triggers: Hashable {
        fileprivate var trigger1 = false
        fileprivate var trigger2 = false
        fileprivate var trigger3 = false
        
        mutating func triggerThing1() {
            trigger1.toggle()
        }
        mutating func triggerThing2() {
            trigger2.toggle()
        }
        mutating func triggerThing3() {
            trigger3.toggle()
        }
    }
    
    let triggers: Triggers
    
    var body: some View {
        // ...

        .onChange(of: triggers.trigger1) {
            // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: triggers.trigger2) {
            // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: triggers.trigger3) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}


An alternative design is to use the environment:
extension EnvironmentValues {
    @Entry var trigger1: Bool = false
    @Entry var trigger2: Bool = false
    @Entry var trigger3: Bool = false
}

struct OnEnvironmentChange<Trigger: Equatable>: ViewModifier {
    let environmentValueKeyPath: WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Bool>
    let trigger: Trigger
    @State private var currentState = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .environment(environmentValueKeyPath, currentState)
            .onChange(of: trigger) {
                currentState.toggle()
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func thing1<T: Equatable>(trigger: T) -> some View {
        modifier(OnEnvironmentChange(environmentValueKeyPath: \.trigger1, trigger: trigger))
    }
    func thing2<T: Equatable>(trigger: T) -> some View {
        modifier(OnEnvironmentChange(environmentValueKeyPath: \.trigger2, trigger: trigger))
    }
    func thing3<T: Equatable>(trigger: T) -> some View {
        modifier(OnEnvironmentChange(environmentValueKeyPath: \.trigger3, trigger: trigger))
    }
}

struct Particles: View {
    @Environment(\.trigger1) var trigger1
    @Environment(\.trigger2) var trigger2
    @Environment(\.trigger3) var trigger3
    var body: some View {
        // ...

        .onChange(of: trigger1) {
            // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: trigger2) {
            // ...
        }
        .onChange(of: trigger3) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

This way, when using Particles, you don't need to know about the triggers that you don't want to trigger. Apply only the view modifiers that corresponds to the things you want to trigger.
// suppose this view only wants to trigger thing1
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var thing1 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Foo") {
            thing1.toggle()
        }
        Particles()
            // then only apply this modifier
            .thing1(trigger: thing1)
            // don't need to care about thing2 or thing3
    }
}


Firstly, thank you for your detailed answer! I appreciate it.
I'm quite confused by your triggering process... it seems to me that I still have to reset the trigger back to false, and then to true again, to trigger another independent action within the view.
e.g. if I want to generate another particle, or a series of them, wouldn't this approach mean setting the trigger value back to false every time?
Cheers.

... the way I see it, the sheet mechanism is a binary operation: the sheet should show, or not.
Whereas I'm in need of multiple, ad-hoc triggers... the trigger is sent, a particle is created. Another trigger is sent, seconds or hours later, and another particle is created etc.

I've edited my question to clarify the issue of particle independence.

@Womble did you run the first code snippet? You can press the button multiple times, and each time you press it, a new list item gets added. Isn’t that what you want? The value of the trigger doesnt matter. It just needs to change.

I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you were doing with the first example.
In that situation, you're not using it as a boolean flag, as such, merely a trigger for any change in the value, correct?
One question: why the use of the Trigger generic? Is that required, or was that just for convenience?
Cheers.

@Womble yes that’s correct. I made it generic just for convenience, as other SwiftUI built-in modifiers do the same too. Sometimes you might find it more convenient to use an existing non-Boolean value as the trigger, rather than creating a new Boolean @State specifically for triggering things.

This is your mistake: Currently, I am using an @Observable view model.
View structs are the view model and use state and binding for dynamic data. Put the state in the highest common parent View that needs it. Pass data down as a let for read only or binding for read/write (transform it if neccessary). Body is called when it changes in either case. This is called data flow. SwiftUI will diff the new body with the previous and use the diff to init/update/deinit the real UI objects, start/stop animations etc.
Seems to me though you might want to model the data that drives the particles separate from the view but it is hard to tell, depends if you want to load/save it.

I am using a view model because the view hierarchy is much more complex than this (somewhat contrived) example.
I'm not sure this is the issue here. I mentioned view model because that's ultimately where any solution will be placed.
